# System call: does Read function change process?

Tags: c, io, operating-system, system, system-calls

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAnDX.png)

I learned that when a system call function is called, the process changes. But what is process B if I call the read function without the fork() function? isn't there is only one process?

Comment: Process B is the highest priority runnable process.  If you list the processes running on your system it is rare these days to have less than 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On x86-64, there is one specific instruction to do system calls: `syscall` (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/syscall.html). When you call `read()` in C, it is compiled to placing the proper syscall number in a register along with the arguments you provide and to one `syscall` instruction. When `syscall` is executed, it jumps to the address stored in the IA32_LSTAR register. After that, it is in kernel mode executing the kernel's syscall handler.

At that point, it is still in the context of process A. Within its handler, the kernel realizes that you want to read from disk. It will thus start a DMA operation by writing some registers of the hard-disk controller. From there, process A is waiting for IO. There is no point in leaving the core idle so the kernel calls the scheduler and it will probably decide to switch the context of the core to another process B.

When the DMA IO operation is done, the hard-disk controller triggers an interrupt. The kernel thus puts process A back into the ready queue and calls the scheduler which will probably have the effect of switching the context of the core back to process A.

The image you provide isn't very clear so I can understand the confusion. Overall, on most architectures it will work similarly to what is stated above.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The image is somewhat misleading. What *actually* happens is, the `read` system call needs to wait for IO. There is nothing else that can be done in the context of process (or thread) A.

So kernel needs to find something else for the CPU to do. Usually there is some other process or processes which do have something to do (not waiting for a system call to return). It could also be another thread of process A that is given time to execute (from kernel point of view, thread and process aren't really much different, actually). There may be several processes which get to execute while process A waits for system call to complete, too.

And if there is nothing else for any other process and thread to do, then kernel will just be idle, let the CPU sleep for a bit, basically save power (especially important on a laptop).

So the image in the question shows just one possible situation.